# Getting error "Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null" in PHP/XML/JavaScript communication

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps

So I am trying to follow the tutorial found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Currently I have the database communication properly set and an XML with the desired results is produced by another file, phpsqlajax_genxml2.php.

However when this is integrated with the Google Map API the console logs the error "Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null" at the line which reads "var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");", which is under the downloadUrl function call.

Here is a snippet from index.html's JS section:

```
var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
```

In case it is helpful, here is the phpsqlajax_genxml2.php file:

```
<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('creeptrekcom.domaincommysql.com', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Which has in its source when inspected:

```
<markers>
<marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Buddha Thai & Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" type="bar"/>
<marker name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" type="restaurant"/>
...

</markers>
```

Comment: Seems like your ```xml``` does not have a ```documentElement```. Are you sure, that you get correct results in your ```data.responseXML```? Have you logged the data to the console, to check that?

Comment: Huh, it seems to be returning null. Though when I load the XML generation file by itself it seems to be communicating with the database correctly and giving me the desired XML. Any ideas for what the cause could be?

Comment: You give a ```request.status``` to your callback. What does it say? Could be helpful.

Comment: It means that data.responseXML is null and that probably means your XML is not valid.

Comment: @Dario - request.status returns 0. epascarello, it should be valid; checking the source on the return file shows the data I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you point a browser at the XML feed and see what it tells you?

Comment: Seems to be errors with [cross domain policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). [Look here](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html) to find out, how to enable requests from other domains.

Comment: geocodezip - I'm unaware of how to do this, please excuse my lack of knowledge!

Comment: It looks to me like the XML is server from the same domain as the page, unlikely to be a cross-domain issue.

Comment: This is true, my bad for not clarifying and overseeing this. There is only one domain involved.

Comment: I seem to have received a couple of downvotes. May I receive some information as to why and how to improve future questions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow cross-domain access. You do so by sending the correct header on top of your php script:

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

But be careful, because you allow access for everyone, not just you, to this resource!

Comment: Hmm, I added this (I also edited my original post with new code if you didn't see), but it still is returning the same error and the markers are thus not showing up. Regardless, thank you for putting up the time and effort to help out, I'm glad to be part of such a helpful community :)

Comment: Note - I didn't mention there was only one domain involved. Completely my bad.

Answer (score 0):

On your php script at `$result = mysql_query($query);` add your connection variable before query parametter.

Something like this: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);`

Make sure the variable name is `$conn` in your database connection file.

exemple: `$conn = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE");`